# how to configure multiple lan card with multiple ip address in windows 10

Tags: windows, ip-address, lan

I have two Lan card in my windows 10. one is default ethernet that is built-in with my laptop and another is USB Lan card.
I want to configure two ip with two lan card.
then how to do that things. Someone says me that i have to add persistent route. i don't have any knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

Press `WinKey+R` and write `ncpa.cpl`.

There you will find both of your NIC.

- Right click on the 1st NIC
- Properties
- Double click on Internet Protocol Version 4
- Configure your IP and DNS under the General tab
- Repeat for the 2nd NIC